# Wrapping a loop in another loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Objective:

- If the user types "right" the first two times, the smiley becomes sad as it can't get out of the forest.
- If the user types "right" 3rd, 4th, 5th time an so on, the smiley becomes frustrated, chops some trees, makes a table and flips it over.
- If the user types anything else, a message showing "Invalid input" is shown to the user and asked to give input again.
- If the user types "left", the smiley gets out of the forest and the program terminates.

Python code:

```
n = input("You are in the Lost Forest\n****************\n****************\n :)\n****************\n****************\nGo left or right? ")
i = 1
while (n.lower() == "right"):
    if i < 3:    
        n = input("You are in the Lost Forest\n****************\n****************\n :(\n****************\n****************\nGo left or right? ")
    elif i >= 3:
        n = input("You are in the Lost Forest\n****************\n******       ***\n  (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻\n****************\n****************\nGo left or right? ")
    i = i + 1    
while (n.lower() != "right") and (n.lower() != "left"):
    n = input("Invalid Input\nYou are in the Lost Forest\n****************\n****************\n :(\n****************\n****************\nGo left or right? ")    
while (n.lower() == "left"):
    print("\nYou got out of the Lost Forest!\n\o/")
    break
```

Bug:

If the user types anything other than "right" or "left" for the first two times and then types "right", the program immediately terminates without giving chance to type "left".

How should I edit my code?

Comment: you probably want to wrap your entire code with a loop that returns back to the top (first while loop, that is).
That loop can for example have a `while(playing==True):` and before the `break` on your last loop, set `playing=False`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AlexYu I tried changing my entire code to `if - else` format, but still unsuccessful.

Comment: I suppose you need to wrap everything into `while True` loop as @Tacratis suggests

Comment: @AlexYu What is `while True`? I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @Simba while <condition> loops while condition == True, so by making condition equal to True, the while loop continues endlessly, or until a break command is reached.

Answer (score 1):

More like this:

```
lost = "You are in the Lost Forest\n****************\n****************\n :(\n****************\n****************\nGo left or right? "
inp = lost
rightCount = 0
while True:
    n = input(inp)
    if (n.lower() == "right"):
        rightCount = rightCount + 1
        if rightCount > 3:
            inp = ("You are in the Lost Forest\n****************\n******       ***\n  (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻\n****************\n****************\nGo left or right? ")
        else:
           inp = lost  
    elif n.lower() == "left":
        print("\nYou got out of the Lost Forest!\n\o/")    #syntax error fixed
        break
    else:
        inp = ("Invalid Input\nYou are in the Lost Forest\n****************\n****************\n :(\n****************\n****************\nGo left or right? ")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you forgot to wrap everything into `while True` loop (or other kind of endless loop).

Is it what you need?

```
while True:
    n = input("You are in the Lost Forest\n****************\n****************\n :)\n****************\n****************\nGo left or right? ")
    i = 1
    if (n.lower() == "right"):
        if i < 3:    
            n = input("You are in the Lost Forest\n****************\n****************\n :(\n****************\n****************\nGo left or right? ")
        elif i >= 3:
            n = input("You are in the Lost Forest\n****************\n******       ***\n  (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻\n****************\n****************\nGo left or right? ")
        i = i + 1    
    if (n.lower() != "right") and (n.lower() != "left"):
        n = input("Invalid Input\nYou are in the Lost Forest\n****************\n****************\n :(\n****************\n****************\nGo left or right? ")    
    if (n.lower() == "left"):
        print("\nYou got out of the Lost Forest!\n\o/")
        break
```

Comment: There are some bugs in your code. If I type "car" first time, it says "Invalid Input" but if I type "car" second time it doesn't say "Invalid Input". One more bug, even after typing "right" more than two times, the smiley never flips the table, it only shows a sad face.

Comment: Those are **your** bugs in **your** code. I did not try solve **all** your needs, I solved only what you marked as a problem - what is below "Bug:" in your question